# id "button" in "headers" reference the header of another column/row

Tags: html, angularjs, sonarqube

I have transferred the SonarQube scanner to my web application. And one of the fixes it is showing me is the following: id "button" in "headers" reference the header of another column/row.

My table contains three  headers. But one of these headers is conditional, it's a pivot table. Because of this, I get the message shown above.

I would like to know what I can do about it to avoid the message.

Should I add an ng-if attribute in the button header? Or within the current header that I have to do it in a more dynamic way without needing the ng-if.

I show my table:

```
`<table class="table table-condensed" aria-describedby="mydesc">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col" id="index">No</th>
       <th scope="col" id="{{WebPage.Elements.NewFieldFilterModal.FieldDataType === 'Valor' ? 'fieldValues1' : 'fieldValues2'}}Header">Valor</th>
       <th scope="col" id="button"></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="FieldValue in WebPage.Elements.NewFieldFilterModal.FieldValues track by $index">
       <td
         ng-bind="$index + 1"
         headers="index"
       ></td>
      
       <td
         ng-if="WebPage.Elements.NewFieldFilterModal.FieldDataType == Configuration.DataTypes.String || WebPage.Elements.NewFieldFilterModal.FieldDataType == Configuration.DataTypes.Number"
         ng-bind="FieldValue"
         headers="{{WebPage.Elements.NewFilterModal.FieldDataType === 'Valor' ? 'fieldValues1' : 'fieldValues2'}}Header"
       ></td>
       
       <td
         ng-if="WebPage.Elements.NewFieldFilterModal.FieldDataType == Configuration.DataTypes.Date"
         ng-bind="FieldValue | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'" 
         headers="{{WebPage.Elements.NewFilterModal.FieldDataType === 'Valor' ? 'fieldValues1' : 'fieldValues2'}}Header"
       ></td>
       
       <td headers="{{$index > 0 ? 'fieldValues1' : 'fieldValues2'}}Header">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="WebPage.Elements.NewFieldFilterModal.DeleteFieldValue($index)">
           <span class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         </button>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>`
```